# How to export user data from two different tables using the backoffice sql manager of Prestashop?

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm not good with sql so i need help exporting my customer's first names, email address, their country and if possible last times they had access to the store.

I managed to get email and first name by using this query :

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, email, active FROM  psdb_customer
```

From what i understood, since the other data is stored in a different db table, i should use a join to get data from both tables but i haven't been able to figure out how

Any help is welcome

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Let's say the customer's country is stored in table called customer_location and his name and email are in a table called customer_data. Data i expect is a table of user's names, emails, countries extracted from those two tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I helped someone with something similar in the [PrestaShop forum](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/872858-how-to-export-users-emails-first-names-and-country-using-the-backoffice-sql-manager/?do=findComment&comment=2931759). This query should work, just remember that to get a country of a customer they should have at least one address registered and of course I'm using the default db prefix:

```
SELECT a.`firstname`,
       a.`lastname`,
       a.`email`,

  (SELECT c.`date_add`
   FROM `ps_guest` g
   LEFT JOIN `ps_connections` c ON c.`id_guest` = g.`id_guest`
   WHERE g.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`
   ORDER BY c.`date_add` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `last_activity`,

  (SELECT cl.`name`
   FROM `ps_address` ad
   LEFT JOIN `ps_country_lang` cl ON cl.`id_country` = ad.`id_country`
   WHERE ad.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`
   ORDER BY ad.`id_address` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `country_name`

FROM `ps_customer` a
```

Comment: Thanks. Somebody else provided me with another query which didn't include the last_activty whereas yours does.

Answer (score 0):

Rolige's answer is what i was looking for.

Here is another query that allows filtering the results by country (using the id_country)

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  a.`id_address`,
a.firstname as firstname,
a.lastname as lastname,
cl.id_country as country, cl.`name` as country
FROM `ps_address` a
LEFT JOIN `ps_country_lang` cl ON (cl.`id_country` = a.`id_country`
AND cl.`id_lang` = 1)
LEFT JOIN `ps_customer` c ON a.id_customer = c.id_customer
WHERE 1 AND a.id_customer != 0
AND c.id_shop IN (1)
AND a.`deleted` = 0
AND cl.`id_country` = '8'
ORDER BY a.`id_address` ASC
```